# Subdomain for WP Mobile Edition and Cloudfare

Tags: mobile, subdomains

Im using WP [Mobile Edition](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mobile-edition) and [CloudFare](http://cloudflare.com). I added the subdomain m.mysite.com in DNS settings in CloudFare and point it to my hosting IP.

But when accessing m.mysite.com, it will display default webpage /cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi. Accessing http://m.mysite.com/msitemap.xml will return 404 page.

How to add subdomain for WP Mobile Edition in CloudFare? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it's hitting your server the DNS in cloudflare is doing it's job.

It sounds like you're using cPanel. I suspect you just need to [set up the subdomain in cPanel](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/SubDomains#Add%20a%20Subdomain) to point to the same directory as the main site (likely public_html).